# Real Analysis proof $\sup T = r + t \sup S$

Tags: real-analysis

$S$ is a set of real numbers bounded above, $r$ is a real number, and $t$ is a positive real number.

Let $T = \{r + tx : x ∈ S\}$

Show that $\sup T = r + t \sup S$

Can anyone provide me with links or start me off with this question? (or similar examples with this question) hints would be appreciated. Not expecting any full answers

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it in two steps; for a nonempty set of real numbers $X$ and a real number $r$, define
$$
r+X=\{r+x:x\in X\}
$$
Prove that, if $X$ is bounded above, then $\sup(r+X)=r+\sup X$.

Second step. For a real number $t$, define
$$
tX=\{tx:x\in X\}
$$
Prove that, if $X$ is bounded above and $t>0$, then $\sup(tX)=t\sup X$.

Put the two steps together for proving your assignment.

The first step should be easy. For the second one, note that, if $u$ is an upper bound for $X$, then $tu$ is an upper bound for $tX$ and, conversely, if $v$ is an upper bound for $tX$, then $v/t$ is an upper bound for $X$.